# How can i repeat <li> in html with help of php

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, foreach

how can i repeat li in this code
I am trying to repeat loop for "< li >" block but it's display me error

```
<?php
$html .=  "

 <li>
    <a href=''>
        <span>Brands</span>
    </a>
    <ul>
how can i repeat li in this code
<!-- i want TO repeat this <li> 5 times start-->
        <li>
            <a href=''>
                <span>ABC</span>
            </a>
        </li>
<!-- end -->
    </ul>
</li>";

?>
```

how can i repeat li in this code

Comment: Do you know how to use a for loop? What have you tried?

Comment: i know how to use for and foreach loop but here value save is variable so i am confuse

Comment: What do you want to be in the <li> ? array or something?

Comment: you should look into HTML parsers also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat 'li' you can use for loop or for each. here i put a sample code in which li will repeat 5 times. Please check this will help you or not
* if you want put dynamic values for each li, you can use array foreach function

```
<?php
$html = '';
$html .=  "

<li>
<a href=''>
    <span>Brands</span>
</a>
<ul>";

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
  $html .= " <li>
        <a href=''>
            <span>ABC</span>
        </a>
    </li>";
}
$html .="    </ul>
</li>";
echo $html;

?>
```